# Validation rule is not working on QuoteLineEditor page (CPQ)

Tags: validation-rule, cpq, steelbrick

I am new to Steelbrick CPQ. I am trying to write a validation on quote line custom object of CPQ. And trying to validate a field on quote lines. But when I am hitting the Save button on QuoteLineEditor page . Validation is not throwing error. Is that something like we can't throw a validation error on QuoteLineEditor using Validation rule.

Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Validation within CPQ, you should use [Validation Product Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_validation_rules_new.htm&type=5) rather than Validation Rules on objects.